# if/else in React Style or CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a React file, in this file, there is a global `myVar` that can either be true or false.

In the render, I have several buttons. Their style is in another a connected CSS file.

I would like to able to change this style based on the value of `myVar`.

This could be done in any way: could change the name of classes of buttons, add style within the React file, etc.

I tried to play with it and make it work, but I didn't succeed.

The relevant part of the Render:

```
   <a className = "firstsOne" onClick={() => this.handleClick("bubbleSort")}> Bubble Sort </a>
   <a onClick={() => this.handleClick("selectionSort")}> Selection Sort </a>
   <a onClick={() => this.handleClick("insertionSort")}> Insertion Sort </a>
   <a onClick={() => this.handleClick("quickSort")}> Quick Sort </a>
   <a onClick={() => this.handleClick("mergeSort")}> Merge Sort </a>
```

The relevant part of CSS:

```
a {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 3.14286;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: -.01em;
  font-family: "SF Pro Text","Myriad Set Pro","SF Pro Icons","Helvetica Neue","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;
  color: #9a9a95;

  margin-right: 120px;
}
```

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Please share the code so we can help you in a proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, for example, conditionally change the `className` based on the value of your variable.

Let's say you have 2 CSS class options, `.option1` and `.option2`.

On your component, based on the value of `myVar`, you could do:

```
const MyButton = ({ myVar }) => {
  return (
    <button className={myVar === true ? 'option1' : 'option2'}>
      Example button
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for the first time, like at the first load of the page, based on the value of myVar, it showed different styles. But from that on if the value of myVar changed again in the functions, it didn't show the update in the styles. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: How are you updating the variable's value? You should have the variable as a state variable, and updating it's value using a setter function.

Comment: Great! If it solved your problem, don't forget to accept as the answer